# Linux join command for several split tar.gz files

Tags: linux

Can someone help me figure out the proper join command or other Linux command to use to recollect all of my tar.gz files into one tar.gz so that I can unzip it.  I zipped up a SVN repository.

**OS:**

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)
```

**Command:**

```
split -b 512m svnrepo.tar.gz svn.tar.gz.1
```

**Result:**

```
svn.tar.gz.1aa
svn.tar.gz.1ab
svn.tar.gz.1ac
svn.tar.gz.1ad
svn.tar.gz.1ae
svn.tar.gz.1af
```

Answer (score 14):

`split` really just splits (and [glob expansion of `*` is guaranteed to be alphabetical](https://serverfault.com/q/122737/90306)), so

```
cat svn.tar.gz.1* > svn.tar.gz
```

should be fine.

Comment: when I do that I get the following gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Hmm, strange. Assuming you have the original file still around elsewhere (512M looks like you wanted to transfer it from a system with a slow network connection), do the file sizes of the pre-`split` archive and the post-`cat` archive match?

Comment: no they're a bit different.  Pre split is 2696328714 and post cat is 2694182410

Comment: I found one of the split files didn't upload fully.